# Sample() in R returning different values in R Markdown

Tags: r-markdown

I've been having this problem for a little while now and I have no idea how to fix it. Hoping someone can help me out.

When using R Markdown, I've been running into an issue anytime I use the sample function with it producing different values for knit documents compared to when it's run in R. For example, say I have code that looks like this:

```
x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
set.seed(1234)
apple = sample(10,5)
dat.train = x[apple,]
dat.test = x[-apple,]
```

Now, if I were to print out dat.test in R before knitting the document, I would get something like:

```
2,5,9,1,10
```

However, when I actually knit the doc, without changing anything in the code, I get something like:

```
1,6,9,4,2
```

Any idea on how to fix this? If I knit it over and over again, I always get the same values for dat.test as I did when previously knitting, and if I run it in R over and over again, I always get the same values for dat.test as I did when previously run in R.

TIA

Comment: Running your code in a clean R session returns the following message: `Error in x[apple, ] : incorrect number of dimensions`

Comment: Instead of showing a "something like this" output, could you show the actual output you get? It's difficult to trubleshoot when even the first output deviates from the seed set (https://rdrr.io/snippets/)